# Weird result in MPAndroidChart library

Tags: android, double, max, min, mpandroidchart

I'm using this library to draw some charts, and now I'm facing an issue. When I try to set a Max and Min value to the Y Axis, if I do with number values like 20f, 60f, etc. there is no problem. But if I try to do it passing a variable with the value, the axis didn't show anything.

Original:

```
YAxis yl = scatterchart.getAxisLeft();
yl.setAxisMinValue(20f);
yl.setAxisMaxValue(60f);
```

Modified:

```
YAxis yl = scatterchart.getAxisLeft();
yl.setAxisMinValue((float)liters_kg_min);
yl.setAxisMaxValue((float)liters_kg_max);
```

liters_kg_min and liters_kg_max are double type. What is the problem?

Thank

Comment: did you try and debug the `liters_kg_min` and `liters_kg_max`, it could be that they have no value

Comment: 20.0 and 60.0 stored in those double variables. I suspect it is because of the difference between of the values, if you write them you put 20f and the value of a float is 20.0, I don't know. I'm very frustrated.